# SQL: Delete by primary key vs by foreign key performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlperformance

#### Wondering if there is any performance difference in following two `DELETE` statements?:

Delete by primary key:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Users WHERE Id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Delete by some foreign key:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Users WHERE Email_Id IN (454,851,909)
```

Suppose we're talking about ~30 million rows `dbo.Users` table, and `IN()` clause contains about 5-200K items.

#### Is there any inbuilt features for deleting by primary-key vs by other field?

Comment: The performance would depend on what indexes, if any, were on those columns.

Comment: Also would depend on how those tables are being accessed during the delete operation.  Potentially, if you hit 5000 locks (lock escalation), SQL could just take out a table lock on the entire thing, it will make it easier for SQL to delete that way but you'll block everything trying to access it.  Also depends on any dependencies the FK has to other tables (CASCADE deletes).

Comment: In what direction will their presence affect the query? Could you add more details please?

Comment: The more indexes on the table that contain that column and data, the more SQL has to go delete, so if you have 4 indexes that have a field in it, you're not deleting the data from one place, but many.  That's why too many indexes hurts DUI operations (Delete, Update, Insert).

Answer (score 0):

If there is no unique constraint on the FK I'd use the PK.  It's guaranteed to be one index lookup for each ID.  The FK maybe you'd have multiples and so you'd be doing a scan on the FK index if it exists (which it should).

Because you've got so many records to delete the optimiser might decide a table scan is the fastest anyway so it won't matter.

To address the bit of your question about whether there is some special feature that makes deleting one way or another better, the answer is not really.  Selection is one thing, deletion pretty much happens the same way no matter how you select the records.   Truncating a table can sometimes be done faster but that's not what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by optimizing the selects
Get a query plan
If you do both it will even show you the relative cost
I suspect the delete part is going to take a lot longer than the where so it will not matter much

```
select * FROM dbo.Users WHERE Id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
select * FROM dbo.Users WHERE Email_Id IN (454,851,909)
```

If you have a big IN you may want to break it up to contain the transaction log

On a really big delete you may even be better off disable indexes on the table and then rebuild them.  Disable every index but PK and delete by PK and the rebuild the indexes.

Comment: What if `dbo.Users`'s primary key is not being referenced by any other tables in the DB ?

Comment: So then good there won't be any FK checks.  Does not change my answer.